# Custom longtable hangs forever when admittedly weird redefinition of \footnoterule is used

Tags: errors, footnotes, longtable, compiling, makecell

Please, nobody ask me ***why*** I have this code ....

The following MNWE does not compile. It does not give an error. It simply hangs forever until I interrupt the process. Because this is pdfTeX and not XeTeX, I can interrupt it rather than killing it, but that is not much use in practical terms.

Something about the combination of the redefinition of the footnote rule and the particular use of `xxxtable` causes problems. If I remove either of these, it compiles. I'm not confident that means it will work in other ways, but at least this much compiles.

```
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\vspace*{-0.18mm}\setlength\leftskip{0pt}\setlength\rightskip{0pt plus 1fil}\noindent{\rule{0.25\columnwidth}{0.18mm}}\vspace*{1.01mm}}
```

This looks very odd to me. I didn't write it, I don't trust it and I don't know what to do about it.

Now I can see the related questions which I looked for before posting, I tried

```
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\vspace*{-0.18mm}\setlength\leftskip{0pt}\setlength\rightskip{0pt plus 1fil}\noindent\hrule width 0.25\columnwidth height 0.18mm\vspace*{1.01mm}}
```

but realised that I don't actually have any idea what the original definition is meant to do, which looks strange even in comparison with the mistaken definitions corrected in answers to related questions.

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{xxxtable}{ m }
{%
  \makegapedcells
  \begin{longtable}{!{\vrule width \xlineht}#1}
    \Xhline{\xlineht}\endhead
    \Xhline{\xlineht}\endfoot
}{%
  \end{longtable}%
}
```

This looks somewhat odd to me. I did write it, but I don't entirely trust it and I'm not sure it isn't the problem.

When I interrupt the compilation, I get

```
 \unvbox 
l.228  \end{xxxtable}
```

as the thing-it-is-stuck-forever-trying-to-do.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array,makecell,longtable,calc,xparse,geometry,kantlipsum}
\newlength\xlineht
\newlength\mlineht
\setlength\xlineht{1.2pt}
\setlength\mlineht{.8pt}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{F}[1]{p{#1}!{\vrule width \xlineht}}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\renewcommand\cellalign{cc}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{xxxtable}{ m }
{%
  \makegapedcells
  \begin{longtable}{!{\vrule width \xlineht}#1}
    \Xhline{\xlineht}\endhead
    \Xhline{\xlineht}\endfoot
}{%
  \end{longtable}%
}
\geometry{top=25.4mm,left=25.4mm,height=234.29mm,width=158.21mm,footskip=24.82mm,headheight=0pt,headsep=0pt,marginparwidth=0pt,marginparsep=0pt,showframe}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\vspace*{-0.18mm}\setlength\leftskip{0pt}\setlength\rightskip{0pt plus 1fil}\noindent{\rule{0.25\columnwidth}{0.18mm}}\vspace*{1.01mm}}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\begin{document}

\kant[1]

\begin{flushleft}
  \begin{xxxtable}{>{\bfseries\arraybackslash}P{54.85mm}|F{\textwidth-54.85mm-4\tabcolsep-2\xlineht}}
    xxxx: &  \\\hline
    xxxxxxx: & xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx\\\hline
    xxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx: & xxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx\\\hline
    xxxx xx xxxxxxxx: & xx xxxx xxxxx\\\hline
    xxxx xx xxxxxx: &  \\
  \end{xxxtable}
\end{flushleft}

\bigskip

\textbf{xxxxxxx x - xxxx xxxxxx}

\textit{xxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx xx xxxxxxxxx xx xxx xxxxxxxx xx xxxxxxx xx xxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx
  xxxxxxxxxx}\footnote{ \textrm{xxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxx xx xxxxxx xx xxxxx xxx/xx xxxxx, xxx xx xxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxx xxxxx xxxxxxx xxxx xxxx xx xxxx xxxxxxxxxx, x xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xx xxxx xxxxxx xx xxxx.}}\textit{ xxxx xxxx xxxxxxxx/xxxx xxxxxxx.}

\textit{xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xx xxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxx -- xxxx}


\begin{flushleft}
  \begin{xxxtable}{>{\bfseries\arraybackslash}P{26.77mm}|P{\textwidth-63.89mm-6\tabcolsep-2\xlineht}|>{\bfseries\arraybackslash}F{37.12mm}}
    xxxxxxxxx & xx xxxxxx xxx xxxxx x xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx xxxxxxx.  & xxxxxx\\\hline
    xxxxxxx & & \\\hline
    xxxxxxxxx & xx xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xx xxxxx xx x xxxxx xxxxxxxx.  & xxxxxx\\\hline
    xxxxxxx & & \\\hline
    xxxxxxxxx & xx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxx xx xxxxxxxxxx (xxxxxxxx xxxx xx xxxxx 80\% xx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx), xxxx xxxxxxx xxxx xxxxx xxx'x xxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx, xxx xx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxx xxxxxxxx xx xxxxx xxxx.  & xxxxxx\\\hline
    xxxxxxx & & \\\hline
    xxxxxxxxx & xx xxxxx xxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx, xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx; xxxxxxxxxx xx xxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx xxxxxxxx; xxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxxxxxxxxx.  & xxxxxx\\\hline
    xxxxxxx & & \\\hline
    xxxxxxxxx & xx xxxxx xxx x xxxxxxxx xxxx xxx xxxxxxxx, xxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxx xx xxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxxxxxx.  & xxxxxx\\\hline
    xxxxxxx & & \\\hline
    xxxxxxxxx & xx xxxxxx xxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx, xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xx xxxxxxx xxxx, xx xxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xx xxxx xx xxxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xxxxxx xxx xxxxx.  & xxxxxx\\\hline
    xxxxxxx & & \\
 \end{xxxtable}
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I won't  ask you why you have this code... :-)

Comment: why have you got that code?

Answer (score 6):

You need to make sure that the footnoterule is a vertical construct

```
\renewcommand\footnoterule{%
  \endgraf\vspace*{-0.18mm}%
  \setlength\leftskip{0pt}%
  \setlength\rightskip{0pt plus 1fil}%
  \noindent{\rule{0.25\columnwidth}{0.18mm}}\vspace*{1.01mm}%
 \endgraf}
```